# Integer+fraction vs Top-heavy fraction

Tags: fractions

What is the name of a fraction like this:

$$\frac{22}{7}$$

as opposed to one like this:

$$3\frac{1}{7}$$

I've never actually had to describe this until today. Not only have I no idea how to describe the top-heavy fraction or the one with a whole number, I also don't even know what the process of changing from the former to the latter is called. Is it merely "simplifying"...? I have a feeling there must be a more technical name, because it's math and there always is.

***Caveat:** This is a very simple question, so much so that I feel sure it must be a duplicate. I did try to search but I was unable to come up with a succinct expression to describe what I am looking for (as evidenced by the fairly lame title of this question) and so the search came up empty.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former is generally called an "[improper fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_fraction#Proper_and_improper_common_fractions)," the latter a "mixed number."

Comment: Wow. That's *nothing* like what I was imagining. Google confirms you are correct, sir. Man, searching is so easy when you actually have the words to search for!

Comment: Apparently I have to wait 11 minutes before I can accept. Eleven. Presumably Math.SE's time limits are all prime numbers or something....

Comment: Frankly, I think I prefer "top-heavy fraction" as a term!

Comment: @Cameron Me too, but even top-empty fractions [prove handy at times.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/312404/23500)

Comment: So now we have busty fractions and topless fractions ...